# dynamically adding new models inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat in an array of object. **testList**  contains name of the test, I want to model the rate and duration and fetch it in my controller. I am able to get the selected value. But rate and duration are not coming .

```
.input-group.margin-bottom-20
             table.table
                thead
                    tr
                        td.col-md-5
                        td.col-md-4
                        td.col-md-3
                tbody
                    tr(ng-repeat='test in testList')
                        td
                            input(type='checkbox', ng-model='test.selected', value='{{test.name}}')
                            |   {{test.name}}  &nbsp


                        td
                            .input-group
                                input(type='text', ng-model='test.rate', pattern = "[0-9]{10}",placeholder='Rate in Rupees')

                            br
                            .input-group
                                input(type='number', ng-model='test.duration', pattern = "[0-9]{10}",placeholder='Duration to deliver report')
```

Comment: If you can provide a codepen/jsfiddle or some other demo I can try to fix this up for you. However, you will probably find the solution yourself when you write it in a codepen.

Comment: Is rate and duration in the array testList?

Comment: no it not in arrayList

Comment: only name is in arrayList , I want to add those two.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your data is coming from for duration or rate but this is how you can  add:

```
    angular.forEach($scope.testList, function(value,key){
    $scope.testList[key].rate = WhateverRate;
    $scope.textLIst[key].duration = WhateverDuration
})
```

Then rate and duration will be a part of your model and will display with your `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Let me know if the above is what you needed.  Without seeing how you are retrieving the data for rate and duration, this is all I could give you.